# Passing props to PrivateRoute Component

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

Hi I have a react (GatsbyJs) app where i am using dynamically fetched data and authentication. I have a PrivateRoute component that checks whether the user is logged in and then redirects to the component or to the login page depending on the status.
I now need to pass props to components but couldn't master it.

Here is the PrivateRouter:

```
import React from 'react'
import { navigate } from 'gatsby'
import { isLoggedIn } from '../services/auth'

const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, location, ...rest }) => {
  if (!isLoggedIn() && location.pathname !== '/app/login') {
    navigate('/app/login')
    return null
  }
  return <Component {...rest} />
}

export default PrivateRoute
```

And the app.js code:

```
import React from "react"
import { Router } from "@reach/router"
import Layout from "../components/layout"
import OrderDetails from "../modules/order-details"
import ItemDetails from "../modules/item-details"
import ProductionOrders from "../modules/production-orders"
import ProdOrderDetail from "../modules/production-order-detail"
import CardDetail from '../modules/card-details'
import Cards from "../modules/cards"
import Orders from "../modules/orders"
import Items from "../modules/items"
import PrivateRoute from '../components/privateRoute'
import Profile from '../components/profile'
import Login from '../modules/login'
import ForgotPassword from "../modules/forgotPassword"
import NewPassword from "../modules/newPassword"
import Invoices from "../modules/invoices"
import Dispatches from "../modules/dispatches"
import InvoiceDetails from "../modules/invoice-details"
import OrderPlan from "../modules/order-plan"
import AccountStatementPage from "../modules/acc-statement"




const App = () => {

  return (
    <Layout>
      <Router basepath="/app">
        <PrivateRoute path="/order-details/:orderId" component={OrderDetails} />
        <PrivateRoute path="/item-details/:itemId" component={ItemDetails} />
        <PrivateRoute path='/production-orders' component={ProductionOrders} />
        <PrivateRoute path="/production-order-detail/:companyNr/:orderId" component={ProdOrderDetail} />
        <PrivateRoute path="/cards" component={Cards} />
        <PrivateRoute path="/card-details/:cardId" component={CardDetail} />
        <PrivateRoute path="/orders" component={Orders} />
        <PrivateRoute path="orders/cId/:cId" component={Orders} />
        <PrivateRoute path="orders/keyword/:keyword" component={Orders} />
        <PrivateRoute path="/items" component={Items} />
        <PrivateRoute path="/items/keyword/:keyword" component={Items} />
        <Login path="/login" />
        <ForgotPassword path="/forgot-password" />
        <NewPassword path="/new-password" />
        <PrivateRoute path="/profile" component={Profile} />
        <PrivateRoute path="/invoices/" component={Invoices}/>
        <PrivateRoute path="/invoices/cId/:cId" component={Invoices}/>
        <PrivateRoute path="/dispatches/" component={Dispatches}/>
        <PrivateRoute path="/dispatches/cId/:cId" component={Dispatches}/>
        <PrivateRoute path="/invoice-details/:invId" component={InvoiceDetails} />
        <PrivateRoute path="/order-plan" component={OrderPlan} />
        <PrivateRoute path="/acc-statement/:id" component={AccountStatementPage}/>
      </Router>
    </Layout>
  )
}
export default App
```

How should I rework them to be able to pass down props to the Component?

Thanks in advance.

P.S.

This is the component:

```
import React from 'react'
import Container from "react-bootstrap/Container"
import Col from 'react-bootstrap/Col'
import Row from 'react-bootstrap/Row'
import AccStatement from '../components/accStatement'



const AccountStatementPage = (props,{location}) => {
console.log(location)
console.log(props)

    return (

        <Container fluid>
            <h1>Cari Hesap Ekstresi</h1>
            <Row className="h-100">
                
            
                        <AccStatement id={props.id} />
               
                
            </Row>
        </Container>
    )
}
export default AccountStatementPage
```

Comment: You are already passing all additional props passed to `PrivateRoute` on to the rendered component when you spread `rest`. I don't see in your `Router` where you are passing any additional props. What/where are you passing additional props to a `PrivateRoute` component?

Comment: İ want to pass props on the <Link> component like so: <Link to=“...” somedata=“....” >

Comment: I see. Can you update your question to include this relevant code then? What and where you are rendering links and trying to pass additional data to the target route?

Answer (score 1):

Your private route component is already configured to pass on *any* additional props passed to it *from* the router, but since you are trying to send additional data to the rendered component you need to send the route state correctly.

[Link](https://reach.tech/router/api/Link)

```
<Link to=“...” myState=“....” >
```

You can access route state from the `location` prop passed to each rendered component.

```
const MyComponent = ({ location }) => {
  return (
    <div>My route state: {location.state.myState}</div>
  );
};
```

If your component doesn't receive the route props then you can use the [useLocation](https://reach.tech/router/api/useLocation) react hook.

```
const MyComponent = () => {
  const location = useLocation();

  return (
    <div>My route state: {location.state.myState}</div>
  );
};
```

> How should I access it in the target component?

`location` should be injected into the `props` object passed to your component by the `Route`. It isn't a separate argument. The route params are also placed on the [`match`](https://reach.tech/router/api/Match) prop and are not a root-level prop value.

Given

```
<PrivateRoute
  path="/acc-statement/:id"
  component={AccountStatementPage}
/>
```

Component

```
const AccountStatementPage = ({ location, match }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    // Log route state and match param `id` on mount
    console.log(location.state, match.id);
  }, []);

  return (
    <Container fluid>
      <h1>Cari Hesap Ekstresi</h1>
      <Row className="h-100">
        <AccStatement id={match.id} />
      </Row>
    </Container>
  )
};
```

Comment: I am getting location undefined from the component. I called the component like so: <Link to={`/app/acc-statement/${card.id}`} state={{custName:card.name, custCode:card.code}}><RiFileList3Line size="1.3em"/></Link>

Comment: @Ergun Sounds like your component isn't rendered directly by a route or otherwise isn't receiving the `location` prop from the `Route`. You can use the `useLocation` react hook to get to the route state. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Yes it is rendered through another component which calls the renderer component. Will there be a problem doing it the way I described?

Comment: @Ergun From what I can tell, `AccountStatementPage` is rendered by the `Router` wrapping your app, so the `location` prop *should* work. Are your links rendered into a different router? Can you update your question with where and how your links are rendered?

Comment: I have only one PrivateRoute component. The Link component is the standard Gatsbyjs component. I don't have a different router. I have the amplify auth wrapper for authentication would that be the reason for that?

Comment: @Ergun That is possible I suppose. Where are you links being rendered? Can you provide that here in your question, maybe even include a link to your source repo if it is public?

Comment: thank you for your help. It is in a private repo, but I can grant you access. I appreciate it very much.

Answer (score 1):

You're really close.

This is working for me. Pass your state object inside `Link` per the Gatsby spec. Then you need to access your `Router` props (which contains the `location` object which has your `Link` state) and pass `location.state.example` to a component like so.

Link

```
<Link
        className="link-wrapper"
        to={endpoint}
        state={{ example: 'something' }}
      >
```

RouterPage (PrivateRouter)

```
const RouterPage = (
  props: { pageComponent: JSX.Element } & RouteComponentProps
): JSX.Element => {
  if (!loggedIn) {
      navigate('/404')
    }

  return props.pageComponent
}
```

Router

```
const App: React.FC<RouteComponentProps> = (props: any) => {
  return (
      <Router className="below-header-container">
        <RouterPage
          path={withPrefix('/some-path/create')}
          pageComponent={<CreateSomething />}
        />
        <RouterPage
          path={withPrefix('/some-path/:id')}
          pageComponent={
            <EditSomething name={props.location.state.example} />
          }
        />
        <RouterPage
          path={withPrefix('/some-path')}
          pageComponent={<Something />}
        />
      </Router>
  )
}
```

Component

```
const EditSomething: React.FC<any> = ({ name }) => {

  return (
    <section className="edit-something">
      <div className="row">
        <h1>{name}</h1>
      </div>
    </section>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `PrivateRoute` component you are destructuring the `component` as a `Component` (to render it), a `location`, and the rest (`...rest`) for rest of the `props`.

To pass a custom prop to your component inside `PrivateRoute`, you just need to access directly your `prop`:

In your `app.js`:

```
    <PrivateRoute path="/order-plan" component={OrderPlan} customProp={`hello`}/>
```

Your `customProp` is passing to your component through `rest` spread operator in `PrivateRoute` so, in your component, just access to `props.customProp`.

If you want to pass something using `Link` component, you should use the state provided by [Gatsby `Link`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/gatsby-link/) itself (because Gatsby extends from `@reach/router`):

```
<Link
  to={`/order-plan`}
  state={{ yourVariable: 'hello' }}
>
```

Then, on your `order-plan` page you have to access to `props.location.state.yourVariable` to get your data.

Comment: Thank you. How can i can pass it from the <Link to=“order-plan”/> ? Can i pass just writing <link to=“order-plan” customProp={something}/>

Comment: `rest` isn't a prop (i.e. there is no named prop `rest`), it's a variable *containing* the "rest" of the props that are passed to `PrivateRoute`, which are spread into the rendered component.

Comment: You are totally right @DrewReese. I've updated the answer @user1305579  with the approach when using `Link`

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work. When trying to access location from the component I am getting undefined.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't access the route state through location. It was undefined all the time.
But I could access the route state through:

window.history.state.customProps

Thanks for your support, be well.